# @Slf4j picking up wrong slf4j interface

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

I have a gradle app that includes the following:

```
implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'
implementation 'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5'
implementation 'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5'
...
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

in my classes I have:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ...
```

However, when ctrl + clicking any log.xxx statement, it takes me to a  slf4j that is part of another library I have, instead of the main lombok one, I have no idea why since the import is from lombok. Other modules that do not have this library go to lombok > slf4j as expected.

It works, but is there a way to force it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Lombok does not include Slf4j, nor does it have a dependency on it.

You have to provide your own.

If you add `@Slf4j`, lombok will generate code that relies on the compile-time and runtime availability of some slf4j-api version, that you have to provide yourself.

If you ctrl-click on `warn` in `log.warn("foo")`, your IDE will take you to the `warn` method in your provided dependency, typically in `slf4j-api-<version>.jar`. If you click on the `log` part, it should take you to the `@Slf4j` annotation at the top of your class.

Disclaimer: I am a Project Lombok maintainer.